# Is there any SEO impact from hosting on Heroku?

Tags: seo, heroku

I want to host a site on Heroku, but I didn't know if it would cause an issue with SEO.  What are the positive and negative impacts on SEO for Heroku?

Comment: Why do you think Heroku would be different than any other hosting?

Comment: @AndrewLott I had heard that Heroku moved content to different servers everytime an app went to sleep.  I figured that might have some effect on SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is like inspector, if they see in your home, you're living with bad people then they assume you're also bad. For example your host IP is `209.168.14.15` and many (say 20) bad website also host in same IP, then Google might assume your website is also bad/spam. Because same home is used by many bad people.

So Google actually **look into IP address not the host**. If same IP address is used by many spammer then hosting your site on that IP address is not good.

And I think most of only developer use Heroku for web hosting, so I think they are good people, so it does not impact negative in SEO.

To findout which website host in same IP, then do a Google search "reverse ip lookup".

Answer (score 1):

The only problems caused by a host for SEO are if it is a well-known host for spam and malicious code or it serves pages too slow. Other than that, the host doesn't matter.